# 'Eclipse Java development tools' installation stops at 48%

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, helios

I have just installed Helios Eclipse IDE for C/C++ developers.

I want to use eclipse for Java programming as well, so I went to Help -> Install new software -> download.eclipse.org/releases/helios -> programming languages -> eclipse java development tools

However, while installing, the **'installing software' dialog box stops at 48%**. If I click 'cancel' and repeat the above steps, it directly starts from 48% and doesn't proceed.

My OS - Windows 10
My Java version - version 8 (build 1.8.0_101-b13)

Sorry if this question has been repeated but I went through several questions and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I've always found it easier to install the Java versions of Eclipse and then install CDT. But uhm... Why Helios? That sucker's about 6 years old. Amazed you still get any support.

Comment: @user4581301 i don't know how I ended up on the Helios download link. I think i will just get the latest version. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an old version of Eclipse (Helios). I downloaded the latest release and the problem was solved.